# Better way to set all the keys to map to false in a mutable map

Tags: kotlin, data-structures, mutablemap

I have a mutable map

```
val weeklyCheck = mutableMapOf(
    Day.MONDAY to true,
    Day.TUESDAY to true,
    Day.WEDNESDAY to true,
    Day.THURSDAY to true,
    Day.FRIDAY to true,
    Day.SATURDAY to true,
    Day.SUNDAY to true
)
```

How do I set all the keys to false. Currently I am using something like this, is there a better way to do this.

```
private fun resetDays() {
    weeklyCheck.put(Days.MONDAY, false)
    weeklyCheck.put(Days.TUESDAY, false)
    weeklyCheck.put(Days.WEDNESDAY, false)
    weeklyCheck.put(Days.THURDSAY, false)
    weeklyCheck.put(Days.FRIDAY, false)
    weeklyCheck.put(Days.SATURDAY, false)
    weeklyCheck.put(Days.SUNDAY, false)
}
```

Comment: I'd find this question clearer if it asked about setting all the _values_ to false — or, equivalently, about setting all the keys to _map_ to false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`replaceAll`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/replace-all.html) - ignore the given key and value, and just return `false` no matter what. This will replace everything with `false`.

```
weeklyCheck.replaceAll { _, _ -> false }
```

Comment: Is there any way to iterate over all the keys and setting the value to false?

Comment: That's what `replaceAll` does... @ARUNSINGH

Answer (score 1):

This can be used to achieve same results:

```
Days.values().forEach { weekFilter[it] = false }
```